# Regular Expressions Change Tags Surrounding Text, Keep Text

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Using Dreamweaver Find and Replace...

I have html like this for example... may different words though:

```
</a>Fish Anatomy</a>
```

that I would like to have like this:

```
Fish Anatomy</a>
```

I would like to rid my code of the first **/a**.

I can match all of those by using regexp:

```
</a>[^"]*</a>
```

However, I am not succeeding at keeping the Fish Anatomy words and just replacing the first **/a**

How do I keep the words and replace the tag?

Comment: I am beginning to think yo ucannot replace like this in dreamweaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty with this would arrive if you have multiple of these in a row, and they are not clearly delineated. What you have described could be done with this regex though:

```
</a>([^<]*</a>)
```

Then replace with:

```
$1
```

Comment: blah! I was using the $1, but within other []... thanks for the help!